# How do I get '&' to show up as text in a MenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile

I want to have a MenuItem with the Text property set to "Tom & Jerry" but, as you all know, the '&' before a character tells Windows that the next character is the keyboard shortcut.

So how does one escape the '&' to show up as text in the MenuItem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a double, &&, but it will be underscored.

Just tested (Wm 6.1 emulator), and TheTXI had the right guess: 4 ampersands, &&&& did finally show up as 1 single. Wonder who thought that up. Will try it on my HTC Touch next.

Confirmed, my Device and the emulator agree. But the Designer can't be trusted.

Comment: This will work fine, and the & will not be underscored.  Not sure how to underscore an &.

Comment: @Brian: Triple it (&&&) to underscore an &.

Comment: What happens when you Quadruple (&&&&) it?

Comment: && shows up correctly in the designer, no underscore; but when I run it in the emulator I get a _ still. Maybe it's not possible on Windows Mobile? It works on Windows, though. Henk gets the answer unless someone can chime in for Windows Mobile.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the &&, it workd and it wasn't underlined.